Is there any ways to not scan full table multiple times in 1 query
I want to ask about any ideas to avoid scan the full table more than 1 times.
My problem is that I need to count number of hiring and departure each year of each department in a company. The dataset provides me with data about hiring date and departure date. My current query achieve this question by using 2 CTEs, 1 for hiring count, and 2 for departure count (each department each years in both CTEs), then join them to show final result. However, I notice that this way force the query to scan full table for 2 times (first for calculate total hiring, second for calculate total departure).
I want to ask is there any other approaches to count both total hiring( by counting number of hiring in a year of a department), and total departure, in just 1 scan. I think it will helps to increase the performance so much. The DBMS I use is Postgres
Here is my query:
WITH hiring_count AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_department_from_date) AS year,
           department,  
           COUNT(*) AS total_hiring
    FROM employee_department
    JOIN departments
        ON employee_department.department_id = departments.department_id
    GROUP BY year, department
), departure_count AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_department_end_date) AS year, 
           department,
           COUNT(*) AS total_departure
    FROM employee_department
    JOIN departments
        ON employee_department.department_id = departments.department_id
    GROUP BY year, department
)
SELECT hiring_count.year, 
       hiring_count.department,
       total_hiring, 
       total_departure
FROM hiring_count
JOIN departure_count
    ON hiring_count.year = departure_count.year
    AND hiring_count.department = departure_count.department


grouping sets

You can use grouping sets. Demo at db<>fiddle:
WITH hiring_count AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_department_from_date) AS year_hired,
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM effective_department_end_date) AS year_departed,
           department,
           d.department_id,
           COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM employee_department ed
    JOIN departments d
        using (department_id)
    GROUP BY grouping sets ( (year_hired, d.department_id)
                            ,(year_departed, d.department_id)) )
SELECT coalesce( a.year_hired
                ,b.year_departed) as year
      ,a.department
      ,a.total as total_hiring
      ,b.total as total_departure
FROM hiring_count a join hiring_count b
  on a.year_hired=b.year_departed
  and a.department_id=b.department_id




year
department
total_hiring
total_departure




2013
department_0
154
8


2013
department_1
315
15


2013
department_2
349
17


2013
department_3
361
18


2013
department_4
341
18


2013
department_5
344
14


2013
department_6
354
25


2013
department_7
347
24


2013
department_8
342
20


2013
department_9
306
18



